# Allow file creation but not download with Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have an application that needs to upload file to Google Drive via the ordinary Google Drive API. It needs to upload, but it never needs to download anything, list directories, read metadata or anything like that. It basically uses Google Drive as a drop box to store results of some computations.

Because of the principle of least authority, I would like to give this application the authorization to create new files, but not read or modify anything. Is this possible? I cannot see anything like this in [this list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth), so I suspect the answer is no, but would like more informed comments.

Answer (score 0):

By principle of least authority "user/process should have necessities/privileges". A file created by an app is owned(create/modify/delete) by app and no access to rest of resources.

If this definition fits in your scope then use

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
```

"Per-file access to files created or opened by the app"

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [Choose Auth Scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes)

> Auth scopes express the permissions you request users to authorize for your app. While many Drive apps can function with just the required set of scopes, you may need to consider using other available scopes.

As far as I know, you can choose from the list of scopes available for the Drive API, combine them or mix and match if necessary. And, you can also add other scopes if your app requires access to any other Google APIs as given in [Google APIs scopes](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2).

To learn more about scopes, you can watch the [video](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes#tips_and_tricks) of Google engineers discussing related tips and tricks within the given documentation. I hope that helps.